# Why did the Baker Shot have a normal mushroom cloud instead of a radial blast wave?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, nuclear-physics, explosions, shock-waves

The US tested its first underwater nuclear device with the [Baker Shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossroads) in Bikini lagoon.  It was supposed to be identical to the Fat Man device dropped on Japan.  However it was measured at 23 kt instead of 19.  This would indicate that a significant amount of the blast rebounded off the lagoon's floor about 130 meters down.

My question is why didn't this produce a spherical blast instead of the normal mushroom cloud we see?   It is my understanding that the mushroom cloud is in a large extent, caused by the vacuum created by the blast and the inward rushing of air that pushes the cloud upwards.  This would not happen under water as the sea simply fills back in the hole left.

Comment: At 30 meters under, the water above basically vanished and the result is like other ground or near ground detonations.

Comment: Thank you...  This was something that I considered but was unsure of..